# leaks at PVC/Metal joints

Tags: leak, pvc, fitting

Have a 1-1/2" irrigation supply system (i.e. PVC run) with at least a dozen joints (PVC to PVC and PVC to metal sections).  I left the main pump on too long without water passing through (auto-off did not engage) and the system (& pump) overheated. Pump still works but apparently the overheated water and/or pressure compromised the seals at several joints.  I was able to fix the leak at one PVC to PVC joint with epoxy (epoxy bonds better to plastic than to metal) but still have drips at two PVC to metal joints.  They're small drips. Replacing the entire run of joints, sections and valves would be a very big job (It's fixed and rigid with no clearance). There is not even enough clearance to cut out the leaking section and install a slipfix fitting because of the max width of the slip fix (I might be able to force it in by cutting into the wall on the far side the section is butted up against).
The leaks are minor and only materialize when the system is pressurized, however I have to address them.  I've read about "rubber bands" with clamps; fiberglass cloth and a couple other fixes (once again, epoxy doesn't seal leaks on PVC to metal joints).  If I took the scorched earth approach and cut out and rebuilt the entire length, with over a dozen joints, I would probably mess up at least a couple joints. New leaks would form, and I'd be back where I started after a tremendous amount of work.  The leaks are very small, the system is out in a small shed out back, and only drips when the system is pressurized.  But I know I have to fix the PVC to Metal fitting joint leaks.  Any advice appreciated!

Comment: If you rebuild it, rebuild it to be maintainable with adequate unions so that it can be serviced. This tends to be the sort of box you get painted into when whoever built the system assumes it will never need to be worked on. Meanwhile, you need two spaces (a blank line) to make a paragraph here, and your wall of text could use some. Also pictures would be helpful ([edit] them in using the "sun and mountains" icon above the edit box.)

Comment: Yes, please add some formatting for readability and some pictures of the joints in question. You'll be surprised at the ingenuity of people around here.